# How to use WebClient.UploadStringAsync to upload byte array?

Tags: silverlight, upload, webclient

I have a working example of `webClient.UploadDataAsync(Uri addr, string method, byte[] data)` in WPF, it calls a RESTful api and works well.

Now I want to call the same RESTapi in silverlight, unfortunately WebClient in Silverlight only has the method of `webClient.UploadStringAsync(Uri addr, string method, string data)`
How can I pass the byte array as a string parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight, the way to upload binary data is via [WebClient.OpenWriteAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144219%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).  This asynchronously opens a writable stream, which can then be used to upload the file (in the event handler).

For a full sample, including code, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622547/65358).

Comment: The problem with OpenWriteAsync is that you can't get a server response.
See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560763/server-response-callback-after-silverlight-file-upload/24362326#24362326 for uploading file using UploadStringAsync.