# How to use WebClient to POST and get a response in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, webclient

Is it possible to use WebClient to POST to a server and get a response?
I'm trying to upload a file via Silverlight to an MVC app.  When I use the WebClient I can successfully upload the file but I need to get the response.  I just can't figure out how.

```
private void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data)
{
        UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:17016/upload/funds/" + fileName);
        WebClient c = new WebClient();

        c.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            input.Position = 0;
            input.CopyTo(e.Result);
            e.Result.Close();
            data.Close();
        };


        c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);

}
```

Comment: Did you try or are you asking us to do your research for you?

Comment: I made my question not suck quite so bad :-)

Comment: There is an OpenWriteComplete event.  Maybe you need to use this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwritecompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I think I've been looking at that API for too long.  Totally missed it.  Good call.

Comment: If you want to "Answer" the question I'll mark it as the answer....

Comment: Haha.  That is the event that I'm using.  However, this event is triggered once the stream is opened.  Not when the response is returned.

Comment: @devlike, look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560763/server-response-callback-after-silverlight-file-upload

Answer (score -2, accepted):

WebClient has an event [OpenWriteComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwritecompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  You can use this to get the results from OpenWriteAsync.

Comment: The appears to return the stream for writing (i.e. posting), not the response.