# WebClient.OpenWriteTaskAsync examples

Tags: .net, webclient

OK, so this one has Google totally stumped. Does anyone have an example of WebClient.OpenWriteTaskAsync where you can also read the response? I understand how to write the request and handle the exceptional cases, but I can't figure out how to read the response.

```
try 
{
    using (var stream = await client.OpenWriteTaskAsync(url,method))
    {
      new XmlSerializer(sometype).Serialize(someobject,stream);
    }
    // at this point the request has been sent - how to get at the response data?
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: The same here, did you find the answer?

Comment: look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560763/server-response-callback-after-silverlight-file-upload